# Quasar Table not updating (v1)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I have a Quasar Table where the data property is connected to a Vuex state (an array of objects).
When the state of an object (a row in the table)  changes, this change is not visible in the table.
If I look with the Vue dev tools, the strange thing is that the QTable Data prop does change but the computedData.rows and the computedRows  do not update.

**How can I force an update to the table rows? I want the changes to be visible in the table.**

In the picture below you can see the table row is not updated but the table's data prop has the updated property.

[image]

In the 2nd picture you can see the computerData.rows property is **not** updated. The same is true for the computerRows property of the table.

[image]

Below is the way the QTable is defined

```
<q-table
  :data="users"
  :columns="columns"
  :selection="showSelectors ? 'multiple' : 'none'"
  :selected.sync="selected"
  :pagination.sync="pagination"
  @update:pagination="pageChanged"
  hide-header
  row-key="id">
  <template v-slot:body="props">
    <q-tr :props="props" @click.native="click(props.row)" v-touch-hold.mouse="longPress">
      <q-td auto-width v-if="showSelectors">
        <q-checkbox dense v-model="props.selected" />
      </q-td>
      <q-td key="name" :props="props">{{ props.row.name }}</q-td>
      <q-td key="phone" :props="props">{{ props.row.phone }}</q-td>
    </q-tr>
  </template>
 </q-table>
```

Below is the code for the input fields:

```
<q-card class="q-pa-md" v-if="showDetails && !showSelectors" style="margin: 10px 0;" >
    <q-icon name="eva-close-circle-outline" class="float-right close-icon" @click="cardClose"/>
    <q-input label="Name" color="negative" stack-label v-model="name" />
    <q-input label="Phone number" color="negative" stack-label v-model="phone" />
    <q-input label="Remarks" color="negative" stack-label v-model="remarks" />
    <q-select color="negative" v-model="locks" :options="Locks" label="Locks" multiple @input="selectLock"/>
    <q-select color="negative" v-model="schedules" :options="Schedules" label="Schedules" multiple @input="selectSchedule" />
    <q-select color="negative" v-model="keys" :options="Keys" label="Keys" multiple @input="selectKey" />
 </q-card>
```

And here are my computer properties. Name and Phone are the properties you see in the table. When you click on a table row, the *currentUser* is set for the form below the table. This is done by `this.$store.commit('users/setCurrentUser', row)`

```
computed: {
...mapState({
  users: state => state.users.users,
  currentUser: state => state.users.currentUser,
}),
name: {
  set (name) {
    this.$store.commit('users/setCurrentUser', { name })
    // this.$refs.table.computedData.rows = this.users
  },
  get () {
    return this.currentUser.name
  }
},
phone: {
  set (phone) {
    this.$store.commit('users/setCurrentUser', { phone })
  },
  get () {
    return this.currentUser.phone
  }
},
```

Lastly here is the code from the Vuex store:

```
import { getUsers, saveUsers } from '../helpers/database'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    users: [],
    currentUser: {}
  },
  mutations: {
     setUsers (state, users) {
        state.users = users
     },
     setCurrentUser (state, payload) {
       state.currentUser = Object.assign({}, state.currentUser, payload)
       const index = state.users.findIndex(u => u.id === state.currentUser.id)
       state.users[index] = state.currentUser
       saveUsers(state.users)
     }
  },
  actions: {
    getUsers ({ commit }) {
      getUsers()
      .then(result => {
        if (!result) {
          saveUsers(seedUsers)
          commit('setUsers', seedUsers)
        } else {
          commit('setUsers', result)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following solution by forcing Vue to re-render a component via **key-changing**

```
<q-table
    :key="tableKey"
...
>
...
</q-table>

data() {
      return {
        tableKey: 0,
}
},
   methods: {
    updateData() {
// Vuex logics or others
      this.tableKey = 1
}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

when you update your user details you can call your table contents again

let see my example:

```
  <q-td key="status_id" :props="props">
                <q-chip tag  :color="props.row.status.color">
                    {{props.row.status.name}}
                </q-chip>
                <q-popup-edit  v-model="props.row.status">
                    <q-select
                            v-model="props.row.status"
                            :value="props.row.status"
                            :options="selectStatuses"
                            :placeholder="props.row.status.name"
                            @input="submitStatus(props.row.status,props.row.id)"
                    />
                </q-popup-edit>
            </q-td>
```

in my methods i have this:

```
 changeStatus(val,id):{
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    return  axiosInstance.put('qc/samples/update/' + id, {status_id: val}).then(response=>{
      resolve( Notify.create({type: 'positive', message: 'Status changed successfully'}))
    })
  })
}

changeStatus(val, id) {
    this.submit(val, id).then(
      this.request({pagination: this.pagination, filter: this.filter})
    )
  },
```

I have two methods: first, when I request to an API route for changing the status and in the second method I submit the status when select input value changes, finally I call my request function for reloading table when I resolve my promise(remember your first function must be Promise)
this is my request function :

```
    request({pagination, filter}) {
        this.loading = true
        axiosInstance.get('qc/samples?' + qs.stringify(pagination)).then(function (response) {
    state.commit('samplesList', response.data.data)

  }).catch(function (error) {
    Notify.create({type: 'negative', message: error.response.data.message})

  })
  }
```